Search and replace within first occured curly braces
I have a text like this in lines
{4 5 6} {8 9 7}
{1 2 3 34 67} {45 85 66 44}

I would like to replace the lines with negative numbers inside the first curly braces
{-4 -5 -6} {8 9 7}
{-1 -2 -3 -34 -67} {45 85 66 44}

I am doing this for now :%s/\d\+/\=submatch(0) * -1/gc but it replaces all the integer numbers.

I would do:
%s/\(^[^{]*{[^{}]*\)\@<=\d\+/-\0/g

It uses the \@<= that verify that the previous pattern matches. More information with :help /@<=
In this case the pattern (^[^{]*{[^{}]*) is made to verify that there is one in only one open curly bracket ({) before the number and no closing curly bracket (}) after that open curly bracket.
The rest is probably familiar:

\d+ matches the number and
-\0 add a minus sign before that number.

